# Add key-value pair to a HashMap with an existing key (Scala)

Tags: scala

I have a following HashMap

```
import collection.mutable.HashMap
val map = mutable.HashMap("key" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value",
                                                    "key2" -> "value2"),
                          "key2" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value",
                                                    "key2" -> "value2"))
```

How can I get the map look like

```
val map = mutable.HashMap("key" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value",
                                                    "key2" -> "value2"),
                          "key2" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value",
                                                    "key2" -> "value2",
                                                    "key3" -> "value3"),
                          "key3" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value"))
```

In my head it would go something like this but I could not find a correct way.

```
map.get("key2").put("key3" -> "value3")
map.put("key3" -> ("key" -> "value3"))
```

Ultimately I want a structure which is easy to convert to Json

Comment: Why not use a case class and use a JSON serializer? There are plenty good ones in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `put` method does not work with parameters in the form of `key -> value`. You have to use `+`-operator. Also `.get(key)` returns an `Option`, so you have to `.map` on it:

```
map.get("key2").map(_ + "key3" -> "value3")
map += ("key3" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value3"))
```

Also in the second line you need to explicitly create a HashMap otherwise it won't match the type of the map (`[String, HashMap]`).

This should answer you question, but Yuval Itzchakov is right, it might prove a good idea to use case classes and JSON serializer such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s), if you have a fixed structure for your objects.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use

`map.get("key2").put("key3" -> "value3")`

because it returns `Option` and it expects two parameters, not a tuple. You would need to unwrap value first by calling `get` and then call it like this:

`map.get("key2").get.put("key3", "value3")`

But there are simpler way to add new values to mutable map:

```
map("key3") = mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value", "key2" -> "value2") 
map("key2")("key3") = "value3"

// or 

map += ("key3" -> mutable.HashMap("key" -> "value", "key2" -> "value2"))
map("key2") += ("key3" -> "value3")
```